# Code is creating segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
/*
  Remove all duplicate elements from a sorted linked list
  Node is defined as 
  struct Node
  {
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
  }
*/
Node* RemoveDuplicates(Node *head)
{
  // This is a "method-only" submission. 
  // You only need to complete this method. 
   Node *ptr= head;
    if(ptr == NULL){
        return head;
    }
    while(ptr != NULL){
        if(ptr->data == (ptr->next)->data){
            ptr->next = (ptr->next)->next;
        }
        else{
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Why does this code create a segmentation fault? This is a practice question in hackerrank, fyi. It says compiler message is segmentation fault.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: On an unrelated note, what happens with the nodes you remove from the list? You unlink them from the list, but what then? Do a search for *memory leak*.

Comment: Please, test the value of `ptr->next` before the if-condition `(ptr->next)->data`.

Comment: Thanks, especially J.Piquard. I just replace ptr by ptr->next in the while loop and it worked!

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use the keyword `struct` when declaring variables.  In C++, a `struct` is a type.

Comment: Note that you also have a design problem. What if the 4th and 7th element are duplicates? The 5th element isn't a duplicate of the 4th, and the 7th element isn't a duplicate of the 6th.

Comment: I forgot to add that the given linked list is sorted in ascending order. Forgive me.